# Background image in kivy not loading from crontab

Tags: python, cron, kivy

I have written a python program with the following bit of code:

```
class MainScreen(Widget):
    res = True
    plastic = True
    paper = True 
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(MainScreen,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.animate()

class Warn(App):


    def build(self):
        return MainScreen()
```

and .kv file:

```
<MainScreen>:
    FloatLayout:
        size: root.width, root.height
        canvas.before:
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
                source: "resources/bg.jpg"
        Label:
            text: "Do the thing"
            color: 0,0,0,0.8
            font_size: 100 
            pos_hint: {"center_x":0.50,"center_y":0.90}
        Label:
            text: "blabla" 
            font_size: 47   
            pos_hint: {"center_x":0.71,"center_y":0.37} 
        Image:
            id: img1
            source: "resources/img.jpg" 
            pos_hint: {"center_x":0.71,"center_y":0.50}
```

When i run this program by hand (typing python3 **main**.py in the command line) it runs fine and the background image shows.

However when i put the following line in crontab -e:
10 17 * * * python3 /home/pi/project/**main**.py
The code runs but the background image (bg.jpg) is not shown. The rest of the program works fine and even the other image (img.jpg) loads fine even when it's in the same map as bg.jpg

Comment: I would guess that the Image widget has more advanced filepath resolution than the Rectangle canvas instruction. Try setting the current directory to your app dir at the start of the script.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work either...

Comment: Then post a minimal runnable example

Comment: editted the question with a cop-paste of part of my code.

Comment: @Bous use fullpath of .jpgs

Comment: I already tried it but that doesn’t work either.

Comment: Your code works in my `crontab` with the minor change of commenting out the `self.animate()` call. And, of course, adding `Warn().run()`. What do you mean by "same map" in your post?

Answer (score 0):

I finally fixed it. For some reason changing the image size and image type (.jpg versus png) solved the problem.

Thanks for the help all!